# Very low voltage BJT behaivor

Tags: transistors, bjt, npn, energy-harvesting, leakage-current

I'm interested in very low supply voltage boosting. 20-200mV, the lower the better. Usually such applications use zero threshold MOSFETs, but I'm curious if BJT will do the work too.

In the datasheet, if I extend the curves it appears that 100nA base current corresponds with about 350mV. Collector voltage is about 35mV. but transistor supposed to have leakage and this leakage alone (B-E and C-E) should be enough to keep the transistor from shutting off (100nA), even at voltages below 0.35V. So this seems to be too bad.

Hovewer, when I try simulator I get that (some generic model) transistors can have power gain of 2 at just 25mV (25mV E-C, 25mV +- 1mV B-E). I assume power gain of 2 is sufficient to run oscillator and then boost the voltage? This seems too good to be true.

Link for particular transistor for 'it depends' people:
http://www.secosgmbh.com/datasheet/products/SSMPTransistor/SOT-23/SS8050.pdf

I think it doesn't depend on a particular transistor, since properties of such small signal transistor appear to be very similar.

TLDR: Make a boost converter from 0.05 VDC supply to 1 VDC output with typical BJT.

Comment: A "generic model" cannot be trusted to simulate accurate behavior. These models are made for **normal operation** so don't draw conclusions from them. The low voltage/low current behavior isn't normal operation so the manufacturer doesn't care about this operating region as almost no one uses it that way.

Comment: *make a boost convertor from 0.05vdc supply to 1vdc output with tupical BJT* My guess: you cannot make one. Boost converters need some current to flow and at low voltages currents are too small. I suggest that you first do your research and answer: *What is achievable with the best technology?* So go to Texas Instrument's website and look at their "energy harvesting" products. What can their chips do performance wise? They will probably be using low threshold CMOS technology, not bipolar. If bipolar was the better choice, for sure they would use that.

Comment: Please explain why your harvester circuit has a power gain?

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka : Energy is provided at 50mv and i need to boost the voltage to 1v. To boost the voltage i need to convert DC to AC. AC power can be measured separately. when i convert the DC to AC i can use the oscillator (LC) to feedback it into the amplifier. This way i can turn more and more of the input dc into ac that i can later rectify at required voltage. If there is gain less than 1, then this operation is impossible and voltage will always stay at given 50mv. TLDR: gain is needed for boost convertor(of any type) to operate.

Comment: For ease in readability and conveying to others that you care about the question, please use proper capitalization. (I've edited this question so you can see the difference.)